# Singularity Isolation-Span cannot clear

Tags: sass, singularitygs

Can anyone help me with Singularity's isolation-span method? It does not actually clear. I placed an article/div (class .special) with isolation-span(4, 3, 'both') and it is overlaid by the two columns (using grid-spans) which should follow. The 'both' is meant to clear any following divs, but doesn't. I had to add an empty div (id = spacer) after the isolation-span and even then had to give that empty div an isolation-span(1,1, 'both') to make it all clear. I have worked away at this using different positions for the breakpoints and this is the only way to get it to work. I have used 'Bundler' to install Singularity 1.1.2 and the various dependencies as Ruby 2.0 gems. I include the .scss. The .left_inset works fine; it's the .special that won't work without my workaround. The HTML is just a few left and right paragraphs with lorem fillers, with grids of 3, 8($breaktab) and 12($breakdesk). Everything works except the .special isolation-span.

```
#main {
    #special {
        border-left: 1px solid white;
        border-right: 1px solid white;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    @include breakpoint($breaktab) {
        .left {
            @include grid-span(4, 1);
        }
        .right {
            @include grid-span(4, 5);
        }
        .left_inset {
            @include isolation-span(3, 2, 'both');
        }
        .special {
            @include isolation-span(4, 3, 'both');
        }
    }
    @include breakpoint($breakdesk) {
        .left {
            @include grid-span(6, 1);
        }
        .right {
            @include grid-span(6, 7);
        }
        .left_inset {
            @include isolation-span(5, 2, 'both');
        }
        .special {
            @include isolation-span(6, 4, 'both');
        }       
    }
}
#spacer {
    @include breakpoint($breaktab) {
        @include isolation-span(1, 1, 'both');
    }
}
```

Answer may be to make the .left block into a float-span like this:

```
@include breakpoint($breaktab) {
        .left {
            @include float-span(4, 'first');
        }
        .right {
            @include grid-span(4, 5);
        }
        .left_inset {
            @include isolation-span(3, 2, 'both');
        }
        .special {
            @include isolation-span(4, 3, 'both');
        }
    }
```

That then compiles correctly and forces the blocks after the isolation-span to clear.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be because you are wrapping `both` in quotes, which is printing it out as a string. Unquoting them prints them as values and clear works fine. Please [file an issue](https://github.com/team-sass/singularity/issues?direction=desc&milestone=4&sort=updated&state=open) letting us know about the quoting issue and we will take a look at it before Singularity 1.2.0 is released.

Comment: Thanks. The wiki clearly shows an isolation span as (4, 3, 'both') with the quotes. I removed the quotes and removed the spacer div. Back to square one with the .special div overlaid by the next two divs (articles, actually). I removed the quotes from the .inset isolation-span and the .inset still worked. I have tried moving the .special to outside the breakpoints ( in other words as a style directly within main. No luck. If I simply drop an isolation-span in without putting it inside a breakpoint it does clear but sits over to the right and cannot be moved into position. I will keep trying.

Comment: For more assistance, please try and replicate your issue in Sassmeister (http://sassmeister.com/) and post to the issue queue

Comment: I have looked at the CSS that is compiled using LiveReload. The two blocks following the isolation-span are class .left and class .right. The class .left has clear right and float left. If I change the CSS to clear left float left, the isolation-span works as it should. So the SCSS does not compile in such a way as to make the CSS work correctly. I will now check through the dependencies to see if something is amiss there. Doubtless, the fault will be mine somewhere!